# Python Imaging Processing (PIL) - changing the overall RGB of an image

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library, rgb

I am trying to change the RGB for the overall image for a project. Currently I am working with a test file before I apply it to the actual Image. I want to test different values of RGB but would first like to start with the mean of all three. How would I go about doing this? I have other modules installed such as scipy, numpy, matplotlib, etc if those are needed. Thanks

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

test = Image.open('/Users/MeganRCunninghan/Pictures/4th-of-July-Wallpaper.ppm')
test.show()
test.getrgb()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your image is stored as a numpy.ndarray (Test this with print type(test))...

Your image will be represented by an NxMx3 array. Basically this means you have a N by M image with a color depth of 3- your RGB values. Taking the mean of those 3 will leave you with an NxMx1 array, where the 1 is now the average intensity. Numpy does this very well:

```
test = test.mean(2)
```

The parameter given, 2, specifies the dimension to take the mean along. It could be either 0, 1, or 2, because your image matrix is 3 dimensional. This should return an NxM array. You basically will be left with a gray-scale, (color depth of 1) image. Try to show the value that gets returned! If you get Nx3 or Mx3, you know you have just taken the average along the wrong axis. Note that you can check the dimensions of a numpy array with:

```
test.shape
```

Shape will be a tuple describing the dimensions of your image.

Comment: I was able to do this successfully, how would I be able to display or see the image with this change?

Comment: Upon some research it seems that PIL uses their own Image type, rather than using a numpy array to store images. Look at the documentation for the Image type [here](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm), it seems there is no 'mean' method, so what I wrote above may not work. However, look on that page and read over the 'convert' method. This will provide what you need. Try `test = test.convert(mode)` and then `test.show()` The documentation doesn't describe what 'mode' should be very well, so you will need to try different values, but one of them should convert to grayscale for you.

Comment: I will try this! I did see the convert method when I did some research but wasnt exactly sure if it applied, Ill give it a shot thank you